# Evaluate if variable contains a value (installscript)

Tags: installshield, installscript

I defined:
`STRING x;` in a header (.h) file.

I have a function that I would like to check if the value `x` was assigned with a value, before I use it.

Something like:
`if(x is null) then...`

How can this be achieved in Installscript (InstallShield)?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Installscript in years, but could you just use [StrLengthChars](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#Subsystems/LangRef/helplibrary/LangrefStrLengthChars.htm#langref_appendixe_4011259752_1031537)? ([example](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#Subsystems/LangRef/helplibrary/LangrefStrLengthChars_example.htm#langref_appendixe_4011259752_1031595)).

***Resources***:

- The Installshield Community: https://community.flexerasoftware.com
- [InstallShield 2018 Help Library](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm)

---

***Some Further Links***:

- [InstallShield InstallScript: Strings](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isp_str.htm)
- [Using Null-Delimited Strings](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/Using%20null-delimited%20strings.htm)
- [Empty String comparison fails during Silent Install](https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?199689-Empty-String-comparison-fails-during-Silent-Install)
- [IsEmpty](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#Subsystems/LangRef/helplibrary/LangrefIsEmpty.htm). [IsEmpty Example](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#Subsystems/LangRef/helplibrary/LangrefIsEmpty_example.htm#langref_appendixc_2808054386_1028846) (Variants)